# Scala Iterator next method caching result?

Tags: scala, iterator

I'm having problems with this code:

```
case class MyIterator(myVal: Int) extends Iterator[MyIterator] {
    override def hasNext:Boolean = true
    override def next(): MyIterator = MyIterator(myVal+1)
    override def toString:String = s"MyIterator : $myVal"
}

object Main extends App {
    val mi = new MyIterator(0)
    mi.take(5).foreach(println(_))
}
```

What I'd like to see is:

```
MyIterator : 0
MyIterator : 1
MyIterator : 2
MyIterator : 3
MyIterator : 4
```

but instead I'm getting:

```
MyIterator : 1
MyIterator : 1
MyIterator : 1
MyIterator : 1
MyIterator : 1
```

and I really can't see why. Does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: The problem here is that Iterator is a mutable structure. A correct implementation of one would mutate the instance every time you call `next`. When you call `mi.take(5)`, you're effectly doing something like `List(mi.next(), mi.next(), mi.next(), mi.next(), mi.next())`.

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes sense. Is there an easy way to do what I want to do?

Comment: your `next` creates a new instance, but it's not treated as the new iterator, because the `Iterator` trait doesn't know that its elements are iterators as well.

Comment: I think you could try implementing an Iterable (or Seq) instead, but I've never done anything like that, so I won't be of much help at that point :(

Comment: Thanks for explaining the problem anyway :) I'll google it

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source for `take` you see that it calls a method `slice`,  which looks like this:

```
def slice(from: Int, until: Int): Iterator[A] = {
  val lo = from max 0
  var toDrop = lo
  while (toDrop > 0 && self.hasNext) {
    self.next()
    toDrop -= 1
  }

  new AbstractIterator[A] {
    private var remaining = until - lo
    def hasNext = remaining > 0 && self.hasNext
    def next(): A =
      if (remaining > 0) {
        remaining -= 1
        self.next()
      }
      else empty.next()
  }
}
```

In the while loop `next` on your iterator is called repeatedly, i.e. the next iteration it doesn't call `next` on the iterator you return, instead it continues to call `next` on the same instance. What you've created is essentially an iterator that will always return a new `MyIterator`, but with the same value each time.

Is there a specific reason you want to implement it recursively? Iterators sort of inherently need to have some kind of state to keep track of which value to return, from the way the trait is written. It seems very hard to implement them immutably in the way that other classes expect them to work. If that's what you're after, take a look at `Stream` instead.

Comment: Yes, I think what I need is called a stream in Scala. What I want to do is use the state of a MyIterator to decide what class the `next` method should return and its state. for example, if myVal == 5 then return MyIterator2(14) or something.